# VBA Excel: get part of range object

Tags: excel, vba

I have a range `myRng` in shape of a column vector with 1346 cells.

I would like to choose the first `100` cells of `myRng` and perform a `For each` operation:

```
Dim cell As Range
For each cell in myRng(1:100)
    'Do something
Next cell
```

What's a proper choice for `myRng(1:100)` to get this operation working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Range](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834676%28v=office.14%29.aspx) property accepts a start and an end cell to limit it, so you could use that.

In your case you would write it like this:

```
For Each cell In myRng.Range(myRng(1), myRng(100))
    ' Do something
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

If myRng is a single column, the ssarabando's will work.  A more general approach, if you myRng has more than one dimension, would be to combine Offset and Resize, or to explicitly declare the column.  eg:

```
Sub foo()
    Dim rg As Range
  Set rg = Range("a1:b1000")
  Debug.Print Range(rg(1), rg(100)).Address '-->$A$1:$B$50
  Debug.Print rg.Columns(1).Resize(rowsize:=100).Address  '$A$1:$A$100
  Debug.Print rg.Columns(2).Resize(rowsize:=100).Address  '$B$1:$B$100

  Debug.Print rg(, 1).Resize(rowsize:=100).Address   '$A$1:$A$100
  Debug.Print rg(, 2).Resize(rowsize:=100).Address   '$B$1:$B$100
End Sub
```